# JMeter2.11 issue with recording SSL a SSO based application

Tags: ssl, single-sign-on, jmeter

Iam using 2.11V of JMeter to record SSO/Https based application. While i start to record, i get the message untrusted site and i un-commented section under SSL configuration and when i started to record, i was able to record. After trying to play back and visualise the results in the tree format, the very first page requested is not available and indicates cookies must be enabled and iam unable to proceed.
If anyone faced similar kind in JMeter usage and SSO/SSL enabled kindly let me know how the issues was rectified for successful recording and play back
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Before recording you must add in your thread group :
HTTP Cookie manager
HTTP Header manager
HTTP Header manager
Also verify that the certificate is correctly installed in your Browser
If in your request there is a authetification request that use login and password, be sure that you are log off of the session before playing back the requests

If this problem persist can you verify the repoone of the failed request to help you figure out the problem